# ImportXML в google таблицах не возвращает данные

Tags: xml, xpath, импорт, google-spreadsheet

[есть сайт](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.ru.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaMIBiAEBmAEhuAEYyAEN2AEB6AEB-AELiAIBqAIEuAKBo430BcACAQ&sid=dc3af449007cde826c0c269ebbcbf4a7&sb=1&sb_lp=1&src=city&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Fcity%2Fru%2Fsaint-petersburg.ru.html%3Faid%3D304142%3Blabel%3Dgen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaMIBiAEBmAEhuAEYyAEN2AEB6AEB-AELiAIBqAIEuAKBo430BcACAQ%3Bsid%3Ddc3af449007cde826c0c269ebbcbf4a7%3Binac%3D0%3Bsrpvid%3Dd816a22bed34002b%26%3B&ss=%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3&is_ski_area=0&ssne=%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3&ssne_untouched=%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3&city=-2996338&checkin_year=2020&checkin_month=4&checkin_monthday=22&checkout_year=2020&checkout_month=4&checkout_monthday=23&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1), надо спарсить названия и цены. Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу достать правильные данные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pZUi.png)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте свой код, пожалуйста. При использовании `requests` сайт не отдаёт первые N элементов, как раз те, которые на вашем скриншоте. При каждом новом запросе первые отели в списке меняются.

Comment: какой код имеется ввиду? =IMPORTXML($A$1;A2)

Comment: А всё, я понял. Вообщем если я правлиьно понимаю там на сайте верхние несколько отелей подгружаются с помощью AJAX. Поэтому таким методом не получится их получить

Comment: не только верхние вроде, первоначально при обращении только эти и подтягиваются. Не совсем понял как получить всё, возможно фильтрация ещё действует

Comment: задачка на 5 мин вроде, а решить не могу 2ой день

Comment: Суть в том, что когда мы делаем запрос, то получаем HTML страничку БЕЗ верхних отелей. Эти 7 или 8 отелей подгружаются отдельно с помощью javascripta, и простым запросом к серверу здесь не обойтись

Comment: Т.е. метод, которым вы пользуетесь, делает обычный GET запрос к серверу, не подгружая javascript, поэтому мы не можем получить все данные